# Multiple kwargs in a function call?

Tags: python

I have a simple function which is called like this:

```
arbitrary_function(**kwargs1, **kwargs2, **kwargs3)
```

It seems to compile fine on my local installation (python 3.5.1) but throws a SyntaxError when I compile it on a docker with python 3.4.5.

I'm not too sure why this behavior is present. Are multiple kwargs not allowed? Should I combine them before passing to function? It is more convenient to pass them individually, for example:

```
plot(**x_axis_params, **y_axis_params, **plot_params)
```

instead of

```
params = dict()

for specific_param in [x_axis_params, y_axis_params, plot_params]:    
    params.update(specific_param)

plot(**params)
```

Comment: this is an syntax error either in Python 3.4 and Python 3.5.

Comment: Yeah, that's not supposed to be allowed. You can *call* a function and unpack multiple keyword argument dicts into the call, but you can't *define* a function with multiple `**` arguments. There'd be no way to decide which argument receives which keywords.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question. it is regarding a function call, not a function definition.

Comment: See ["Additional Unpacking Generalizations"](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448) in python 3.5 changelog and the linked [PEP-448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a new feature introduced in Python 3.5. If you have to support Python 3.4, you're basically stuck with the `update` loop.

People have their own favored variations on how to combine multiple dicts into one, but the only one that's really a major improvement over the `update` loop is 3.5+ exclusive, so it doesn't help with this. (For reference, the new dict-merging syntax is `{**kwargs1, **kwargs2, **kwargs3}`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `*args` instead, e.g.:

```
plot(*[x_axis_params, y_axis_params, plot_params])
```

And then within the function:

```
def plot(*args):
    x_axis_params = args[0]
    y_axis_params = args[1]
    plot_params   = args[2]
return None
```

If you want several `**kwargs` when e.g. initialising class attributes then you can also do something like `self.__dict__.update(**x_axis_params)`

Answer (score 1):

One workaround [mentioned in the rationale for PEP448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#rationale) (which introduced that Python feature) is to use [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
from collections import ChainMap

plot(**ChainMap(x_axis_params, y_axis_params, plot_params))
```

`ChainMap` was introduced in Python 3.3, so it should work in your docker instance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @egorauto 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72378830/14458256),
, I applied egorauto's approach to Kwargs and found it to be much more 'handy' the other ways like using a `for key,value in kwargs.items()` loop clause / etc.
In retrospect, this *seems* obvious, but for some reason I just hadn't tried it. Since it helped me I'm posting here too.

e.g.,

```
def test(name,**kwargs):
    typex = kwargs['typex']
    adjective = kwargs['adjective']
    
    if typex == 'cat':
        print(f"{name} is a {adjective} {typex}.")
        
    elif typex == 'human':
        gender = kwargs['gender']
        
        print(f"{name} is a {adjective} {gender}.")
```

this easily accomodates calling the minimum necessary kwargs for the context:

```
test(name='meowsie',typex='cat',adjective='cool')
```

> "meowsie is a cool cat"

or

```
test(name='john',typex='human',adjective='young',gender='boy')
```

> "john is a young boy"

Sorry I didn't adapt the example specifically to OP, but I had to rush. I think its clear to see you would use '`x_axis_param`' instead of *typex*, '`y_axis_param`' instead of *adjective*, etc.