# translate py3 unpacking to py2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

Trying to translate [brickftp](https://github.com/octoenergy/BrickFTP/blob/master/brickftp/client.py) to python 2 and I got stuck with this line:

```
resp = getattr(requests, method)(
    url, **{**self._default_request_kwargs, **kwargs}
)
```

where:

```
 @property
 def _default_request_kwargs(self):
     if self._logged_in:
         return {'cookies': {'BrickAPI': self._session_id}}
     elif not self._logged_in and self._session_id:
         return {'auth': (self._session_id, 'x')}
     else:
         return {}
```

what is the python 2 equivalent of this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe multiple kwargs support was added "recently", see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860676/multiple-kwargs-in-a-function-call