# how to pass multiple kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to python (scrapy framework) and trying to achieve the following requirement:

`scrapy crawl ispider01 -a "urls=http://www.example1.com, http://www.example2.com" -a "keywords = email, contactus"`

for "urls" portion I am able to achieve with the following :

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    urls = kwargs.pop('urls', []) 
    if urls:
        self.start_urls = urls.split(',')
    #self.logger.info(self.start_urls)
    super(QuotesSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

but in order to achieve for the keywords, what can i do ?

I read [Multiple kwargs in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860676/multiple-kwargs-in-a-function-call) that we can pass multiple **kwargs in a function. but it gives me a syntax error on  adding second **kwargs01 when i run the spider.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860676/multiple-kwargs-in-a-function-call

Comment: not a duplicate at all. I m trying to understand how can we pass multiple kwargs without syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

kwargs is just a dict and may look like this:

```
kwargs = {
    "urls": "http://www.example1.com, http://www.example2.com",
    "keywords": "email, contactus"
    }
```

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    urls = kwargs.pop('urls', []) 
    if urls:
        self.start_urls = urls.split(',')
    #self.logger.info(self.start_urls)

    keywords = kwargs.pop('keywords', []) 
    if keywords:
        self.start_keywords = keywords.split(',')
    #self.logger.info(self.start_keywords)

    super(QuotesSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to pass two dicts as `**kwargs` to a method, you need to merge them before:

`kwargs = { **dict1, **dict2 }`

Comment: Thanks, but still getting error at: 

  File "E:\Python\Scrapy\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\ispider02.py", line 11
 ```  
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs, **kwargs001):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You can't pass multiple kwargs, but you can merge them, when/before you pass them. new_kwargs = {**kwargs,**kwargs001}

Comment: Thanks again,  i m new to all this, how would i declare in my function like, what you have mentioned ? 
Am i doing correctly?
def __init__(self, *args, new_kwargs={**kwargs,**kwargs001}):
    urls = kwargs.pop('urls', []) 
    if urls:
        self.start_urls = urls.split(',')
    #self.logger.info(self.start_urls)
    super(QuotesSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: i was actually trying to do this but not very sure, You rock!!! :)

Comment: Thx! I'm glad I was able to help.